# What I do wrong with Low Search and Tag in result page?

Tags: search, low-search, solspace-tag

I try to understand how Low Search works and been trying to get Solspace Tags as human words instead of ID's in my result page like: Your search keywords were: foo, bar.

But I dont understand what I need to do to make this happen.

Here is example with what I have tried a lot of different setups with no luck.

Would be thankful if someone point me what's wrong, thanks.

```
<p>Your keywords: <strong>{exp:low_search:param:loop get="tag_id" as="tag_name" query="{segment_3}"} {exp:tag:tag_name}{tag}{/exp:tag:tag_name}{/exp:low_search:param:loop}</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using tag IDs, then you can use the [Cloud tag](http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/cloud/) to display the names.

The most important thing you'll read about Low Search is [**how parameters work**](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters). With that in mind, if you follow [this example](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/examples#tags-1), then you could use this code to display the tags:

```
{exp:low_search:filters query="{segment_3}"}
  {exp:tag:cloud tag_id="{low_search_tag_id}"}
     {tag}
  {/exp:tag:cloud}
{/exp:low_search:filters}
```

Comment: Thanks Low. I need to study them more so that I can start to understand basics.